# C++ return type of function

Tags: c++

```
const int& foo(int i)
{
    return i;
}
```

As a computer science student, I am wondering how this function works. In the function declaration the return type is a const reference to a int, but inside the function what we passed is just an int, most of the intro book I have read says return type should match what we return, can anyone help me to understand what is actually happening?

Comment: Can I assume there is something like const int& temp = I; and the thing returned from this function is temp?

Comment: Without any optimization, yes. With optimization,.things can be different.

Comment: Could you please show me an optimized example? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I can't. By "optimize" I mean things done by the compiler, usually by supplying option `-O2` to it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's undefined behavior aka it's wrong. It compiles, because you can return an int as reference to inr.

Comment: AFAICT there's no practical difference between `const T&` and `T` for simple types (char, int, float, etc.). You should always use `T` without using references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the function declaration the return type is a const reference to a int, but inside the function what we passed is just an in

C++ has implicit conversions, for example:

```
double function(int n) {
  return n;
}
```

There is an implicit conversion from int to double.

In your case, you have a conversion from int to a reference. That's correct and compiles, but in this case your variable will be "removed" in the end of the function. That can be a problem if you use it later, this is considered a [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)